# Redirect URL when last character of URL matches a regex

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config

I noticed in my logs the following errors:

```
Exception Type: 
System.Web.HttpException
Exception: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
Stack Trace: 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

This happens when there's a colon at the end of the URL, and this can be caused by email software that includes the colon in a email written as *"my site is at www.someurl.com: you'll find the info"*.

I want to rewrite and redirect every URL that ends with a colon to the same URL without the colon in last position.

This is what I have: an entry I add in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite without last colon">
        <match url="[:]\z" /> //not sure this is correct
        <action type="Rewrite" url="not sure what to put" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="Remove colon" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*):$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>

(.*) = everything before the :
$ = end of the string to be matched
```

References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Thanks! This looks good; I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know!